# is there any way of binding to a specific row in an array without using v-for in vue js.?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, model-view-controller

We are using vue 3 js within our old mvc 5 app. We want to take advantage of the @Html editors and still bind to a vue js view model. Our view model has an array of object like so:

```
export let vueApp = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            changeSupervisorRequestData: {
                changeSupervisorRequestsList: [
                    {
                        Id: "1",
                        requestId: "123456",
                        StudyProgram: undefined,
                        studentId: "123456",
                        studentName: "John Doe",
                        studentNameAndId: "John Doe (123456)",
                        comments: "This is a comment",
                        requestReassignment: false
                        
            }]
```

This array is populated after the mvc model is populated as so:

vueApp.changeSupervisorRequestData = @Html.HtmlConvertToJson(Model);

We have about 10 rows in the 'changeSupervisorRequestsList' array.

I want to use the mvc way of looping round the model and creating the html fields:

```
var index = 0;

 foreach (var item in Model.ChangeSupervisorRequestsList)
 {
     <tr>
         <td>
             @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.RequestReassignment,
                 new { v_model = "changeSupervisorRequestData.ChangeSupervisorRequestsList[index].requestId" })
         </td>
         <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudyProgram.DepartmentCode)
         </td>
         <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudyProgram.Term)
         </td>
```

We want to be able to bind to the vue js array via an index value (see above v_model value). It just doesn;t seem to work?

Any ideas? I'd rather not lose the extra stuff that the editor templates give us so rather not use v-for loop

Comment: You should generate the table using Vue over JSON Data. If it's generated in backend, then it will not be bound in Vue.